# Django NameError urls.py

Tags: python, django, sitemap, django-urls, nameerror

Im getting a name error: `name sitemaps is not defined` from my urls.py when I try to integrate sitemaps with my application.

From my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap

(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

Is there something wrong with this regular expression from my urls.py? Or is there another problem going on?

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you will do something like this -

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap, FlatPageSitemap

sitemaps = {
  'site': Sitemap,
  'flatpages': FlatPageSitemap,
}

# ..
# Some url patterns. urlpatterns must be defined by now
# ..

urlpatterns += patterns("",
  url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 
      'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', 
      {'sitemaps': sitemaps}
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#initialization):

> `sitemaps` should be a dictionary that maps a short section label (e.g., `blog` or `news`) to its `Sitemap` class (e.g., `BlogSitemap` or `NewsSitemap`). It may also map to an *instance* of a `Sitemap` class (e.g., `BlogSitemap(some_var)`).

So... define it.