# Django 1.6: name 'Sitemap' is not defined

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-sitemaps

I'm stuck into this issue on Django 1.6

This is my `sitemaps.py`

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from datetime import datetime

class ContratalosSitemap(Sitemap):

def __init__(self, names):
    self.names = names

def items(self):
    return self.names

def changefreq(self, obj):
    return 'weekly'

def lastmod(self, obj):
    return datetime.now()
```

This is my `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from sitemaps.py import ContratalosSitemap

#Declaration for sitemaps url

sitemaps = {
    'pages' : ContratalosSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = patterns(
'apps.contratalos.views',
url(r'c/(?P<slug>\.*[^ ]{1,128})?/', 'c', name='content'),
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',    {'sitemaps'$
)
```

I'm stuck into this, what could be the cause?

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378656/django-nameerror-urls-py) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220561/django-1-6-name-sitemaps-is-not-defined)

But no luck yet =/

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `import sitemap` you only imported the module name. So if you want to use something in the module, you would need too write `sitemap.Sitemap`.

If you write `from sitemap import Sitemap` you specifically import the Sitemap class from the module and can use it directly, just like in your code.

You can also do `from sitemap import *`, which will import all definitions in the module. But it is not recommend, since you probably only use a few names from it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your class definition to class `ContratalosSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):` and it should work